# MySQL not giving me the correct amount of decimal places

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT  CAR_ID
     , AVG(ROUND(TRAVEL_PRICE * TRAVEL_DISCOUNT,2)) AS DISCOUNT_AMOUNT
  FROM  TRAVELS
 WHERE TRAVEL_DISCOUNT IS NOT NULL
 GROUP 
    BY  CAR_ID
```

Its returning

```
CAR_ID  DISCOUNT_AMOUNT
1002    3.513333
1003    6.280000
1004    0.620000
```

How do I get 2 decimal places?

Comment: You are not rounding the result of `AVG`.

Comment: You must do first AVG an then  ROUND, not the way you do

Comment: So what would I change?

Comment: First AVG, then Round: `ROUND(AVG(TRAVEL_PRICE * TRAVEL_DISCOUNT),2)`

Comment: @nacho no, it should likely be round both before and after avg. the round inside calculates the actual discount amount for a given row, and should specify 2 decimal places (unless you are using one of the very few world currencies that have something other than 2 decimals). the outer round should specify whatever precision they want the average to show.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  CAR_ID, ROUND(AVG(TRAVEL_PRICE * TRAVEL_DISCOUNT),2) AS DISCOUNT_AMOUNTFROM  TRAVELS WHERE TRAVEL_DISCOUNT IS NOT NULL GROUP  BY  CAR_ID
```

1. Your code should be like this. First do the AVG after then you ROUND.

Comment: When I do that its returning the first row as 5.32 when the answer is 5.31... any idea how to fix that?

Comment: can you add your sample data for that first car to the question, ideally as create table and insert statements in a fiddle e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5

Comment: ROUND(AVG(ROUND(TRAVEL_PRICE * TRAVEL_DISCOUNT,2)),2) this might work

Answer (score 1):

So from your data, the average for car_id 1002 is 3.51 and a third cent.  If you want that rounded to 2 decimal places, simply add a round around the average:

```
SELECT  CAR_ID
     , ROUND(AVG(ROUND(TRAVEL_PRICE * TRAVEL_DISCOUNT,2)),2) AS DISCOUNT_AMOUNT
  FROM  TRAVELS
 WHERE TRAVEL_DISCOUNT IS NOT NULL
 GROUP 
    BY  CAR_ID
```

Comment: @RobertMarsella The best way to thank a person is to accept their answers.